# SQL Server 2008 R2 Backup

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I see this error message in log

> BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE model. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.

SQL Agent is disabled. I never issued backup command. There is a single user database on this server. I don't know what's going on?

Comment: Maybe someone ran a backup using SSMS?

Comment: Only I have access to Remote. I see no other unusual activity on server.

Answer (score 0):

"Model" is one of the 4 system databases that comes with SQL Server.   Most likely the SQL Server takes automatic backups of its core from time to time to cleanup transactions or something?  I wouldn't imagine you should be worried about that backup command.

Comment: This message also repeats for a user database and other core databases at the same time.